# Is there a way to open a CMD window with a running command through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

I know it is possible to use a batch file, but due to a suggestion I switched a lot of my script over to PowerShell. The problem I ran into is that PowerShell is still missing some commands from CMD and has lower permissions when run as an Admin. Below is the current line I have been using.

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'cmd' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList 'del /s "C:\Users\*.mp3"'"
```

I ran it in both 5.1 and 7.
It works with a simple command like opening the calculator or sending a ping, but I can't get the `del` command to work. The goal is to open a CMD window which will then delete all mp3 files. I know there are probably better ways to do this, but I more so want to know if it's possible than efficient. Thank you for your time!

Comment: PowerShell definitely knows how to delete files, though. Do you really need to run `cmd` or would you also be satisfied knowing how to run a recursive delete in PowerShell (`dir c:\ -filter "users*.mp3" -recurse -erroraction ignore | del -whatif`, remove `-whatif` once you're satisfied it works)? Also note that PowerShell does *not* "have lower permissions when ran as admin"; if you're lacking administrative permissions you likely didn't start the prompt with elevation. This works the same as in `cmd`.

Comment: `PowerShell is still missing some commands from CMD` definitely that's not true. PowerShell can do everything cmd can and far more because it extremely powerful

Comment: The only way this would need to be Run as administrator, _(elevated)_, would be if you weren't the owner of those files. I'd love to know in what scenario this script would genuinely need to delete every single `.mp3` file in the local profiles of every user. I call malice!

Comment: @Compo I am in a cybersecurity competition and we have something called a no fun policy. Basically mean there should be no media files on the computer. You are given a admin account and have to modify a vm. I found deleting the files was simply easier than searching for them.

Comment: @Jeroen-Mostert Thanks for your response! I will have to look into your suggestions as I currently don't have the VM with me. I have ran powershell as administrator, but when running certain commands have been denied access in a way I never experienced with CMD. Do you know what the reason could be?

Comment: mp3 files can quite legitimately form part of software programs files, which can reside within the appdata subdirectory structure. You should not  just delete them all under some misguided idea that they can only be included for **fun**. Notwithstanding the *fun** should not be categorized as a 'cybersecurity' issue. A properly designed safe VM should have specific locations designed, for persistence, the rest should be returned to their initial state upon reboot. This way only those specific locations would need to be scanned for malice or fun, not every user profile tree.

Comment: @Compo it’s obvious we have varying opinions on the matter. I completely agree that in real life it would be absolutely idiotic to do what I’m doing, but in all honesty the competition isn’t designed very well. It is scored by a scoring engine. It literally just checks and sees if the files are there or not. I understand that what I’m doing is probably the worst way of going about this but either way the original question would still allow me to use batch from within my powershell script. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This works somewhat

`Start-Process cmd "/c del /S C:\Users\*.mp3"`